# an error occurred while installing jplayer and audiofield module on server in drupal 7

Tags: 7

I tried to install [jplayer](https://drupal.org/project/jplayer) and [audiofield](http://drupalmodules.com/module/audiofield) modules on server but the following error reported and I could not understand what it is and how to solve it:

An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. Path: http://**mywebsite.com**/authorize.php?batch=1&render=overlay&id=28&op=do StatusText: Internal Server Error ResponseText: UnexpectedValueException: RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/home/**username**/public_html/C:/xampp/tmp/update-extraction-7a580f22/jplayer) [recursivedirectoryiterator.--construct]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct() (line 408 of /home/**username**/public_html/includes/filetransfer/filetransfer.inc

I installed these modules on `localhost` and there was no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a temp directory and give 777 permission and change file system's temporary directory from 'admin/config/media/file-system' to that temp directory. Because C:/xampp/tmp/ doesn't exist on your server.

Comment: I checked `public_html` and `C:/xampp/tmp/ ` is on my server, besides that those modules were also copied there. how can I create a temp directory and how to notify the server that this is temp directory ? can I do this thing from CPanel or I should contact the server administrator ?

Comment: If your CPanel allows to access to the root of your Drupal Installation, then just create a temp directory or create it via FTP. or contact your server admin.

Comment: at `/home` directory there is folder named `tmp` is this the temp directory ? if not where should I create temp directory and what must be its name ?

Comment: ok, then just open 'admin/config/media/file-system' and enter /home/tmp to Temporary input. Before doing this just check for permission of that directory. Because temporary folder must be writable.